# 'preview timed out while rendering the layout infinite loop or unbounded recursion' when I duplicated some TableRows

Tags: android, recursion, render, tablelayout, tablerow

I'm just making an app which will work as an answersheet. I kept TableLayout for containing the various questions in rows and their multiple choices in the columns
So I 'copy-pasted' this TableRow code 11 times for 11 questions

```
    <TableRow
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">



    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="C"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="D"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</TableRow>
```

But there was rendering error saying 'infinite loop or unbounded recursion'

My activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_row="5"
android:layout_column="5"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

<TableRow
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">



    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="C"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="D"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">



    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="C"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="D"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</TableRow>



</TableLayout>
```

I want to create something like this with 11 questions
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JpNJ.png)

here's the stack trace

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Preview timed out while rendering the layout.
This typically happens when there is an infinite loop or unbounded recursion in one of the custom views.
at java.util.ArrayList.indexOf(ArrayList.java:317)
at java.util.ArrayList.contains(ArrayList.java:300)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.DelegateManager.addNewDelegate(DelegateManager.java:132)
at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable_Delegate.nCreateTree(VectorDrawable_Delegate.java:94)
at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.nCreateTree(VectorDrawable.java)
at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.access$300(VectorDrawable.java:204)
at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState.createNativeTree(VectorDrawable.java:824)
at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState.access$000(VectorDrawable.java:761)
at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:581)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:130)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1224)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1197)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:316)
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getDrawable(Resources_Delegate.java:142)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:763)
at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable.inflate(AnimatedVectorDrawable.java:373)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:130)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1224)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1197)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:316)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:687)
at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.parseTransition(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:473)
at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:455)
at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedStateListDrawable.inflate(AnimatedStateListDrawable.java:385)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:130)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1224)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1197)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:316)
at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getDrawable(Resources_Delegate.java:142)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:763)
at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:133)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:352)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:181)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCompoundButtonHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatCompoundButtonHelper.java:64)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox.<init>(AppCompatCheckBox.java:61)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox.<init>(AppCompatCheckBox.java:54)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor363.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:186)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:312)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:141)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:210)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:317)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$61(RenderTask.java:659)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$$Lambda$141/4860208.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: try refresh the editor

Answer (score 30):

Try this:

Build -> Rebuild Project

This helps me to get rid of this error. I didn't change any of my code.

Answer (score 2):

- build APK
- rebuild Project

this will do

Answer (score 2):

For me, Restarting Android studio worked after doing clean build.

Answer (score 1):

Going to **another layout** which does not have this issue, and **coming back** again to the layout which was facing this issue worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

go to style.xml and change parent as Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar